# how to align radio button with image horizontally

Tags: html, css

i can't get this radio button with image horizontally e.g radio-image,radio-image,radio-image etc.
can someone help me out. The html code is

```css
fieldset.optionGroup {
  float: none;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

fieldset.optionGroup label {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  width: 100px;
}

fieldset.optionGroup input {
  float: none;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="CreditCard">
  <legend>Credit Card (required)</legend>

  <fieldset class="optionGroup">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="ccard"><img src="discover.png" alt="discover card">
    </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="ccard"> <img src="diners.png" alt="diners card">
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="ccard"><img src="master.png" alt="master card">
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="ccard"><img src="visa.png" alt="visa card">
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UmAJe/)

Answer (score 4):

Use `position` css rule.

```
fieldset.optionGroup input {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -16px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

#### [**`Demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/UmAJe/5/)

Comment: only thing that moves is the button.. image don't move at all

Comment: thank you all for the suggestion..i just figured out.. need to display: inline in input and made the label width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Give this:

```
fieldset.optionGroup,
fieldset.optionGroup label,
fieldset.optionGroup input
{
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: As you said, there's `display: inline;` and `vertical-align` except the `width`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this one line to your css and it should work:

```
fieldset img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```